# Find number in text with leading zero

Tags: excel, vba, text, format, numbers

In part of my project, I need to find number from pivot table in text array given by structure of the table, the problem is with numbers stored as text with leading zero, all others are working fine

My code:

```
Dim wbname As String
Dim wsp As Worksheet, wspsqa As Worksheet
Dim lcol As Long, lrow As Long
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, x As Integer, r As Integer, RowCount As Integer, FR As Integer, LR As Integer, z As Integer, t As Integer

Dim catID As Variant
Dim sInt As Range

wbname = "SUMMARY*.xlsx"
Set wbSUM = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSUM = wbSUM.Sheets("IKOS")
Set wsH = wbSUM.Sheets("SQA - H")
Set wsN = wbSUM.Sheets("SQA - N")
Set wsZ = wbSUM.Sheets("SQA - Z")
Set wsO = wbSUM.Sheets("SQA - O")
wsSUM.Activate

'get number of lines in
        Rows("3:3").Find(What:="Total to IKOS").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    i = Selection.Rows.Count

Set wsp = Worksheets("Pivot")
lcol = wsp.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lrow = wsp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For z = 2 To lrow
        For n = 5 To 8
            If wsp.Cells(z, lcol + n).Value <> "" Then
            catID = wsp.Cells(z, lcol + n).Value
                'sInt = CInt(wsSUM.Range("D4:D" & i))
                If wsSUM.Range("A4:A" & i).Find(What:=catID) Is Nothing Then
                    t = wsSUM.Range("D4:D" & i).Find(What:=Left(catID, 9)).Row
                    'Debug.Print Left(catID, 9)
'declare row number
                        wsSUM.Rows(t + 1 & ":" & t + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                        wsSUM.Range("D" & t + 1).FillDown
                        wsSUM.Range("P" & t + 1).FillDown
                        wsSUM.Range("A" & t + 1).FillDown
                        With wsSUM.Range("E" & t + 1)
                            .FormulaR1C1 = wsp.Cells(z, 2).Value
                            .NumberFormat = "@"
                        End With
                        
'get row number for period merged cells
                            RowCount = wsSUM.Range("C" & t).MergeArea.Rows.Count
                            FR = wsSUM.Range("C" & t).MergeArea.Row
                            LR = wsSUM.Range("C" & t).MergeArea.Row + wsSUM.Range("C" & t).MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1
    
'sort data
                        With wsSUM.Sort
                            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("E" & FR + 1 & ":E" & LR), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                            .SetRange Range("E" & FR + 1 & ":Q" & LR) 'podle cisla sloupce, merged cell
                            .header = xlYes
                            .MatchCase = False
                            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                            .Apply
                        End With
                        
                        i = i + 1 'with every added line is needed to broaden count
'                    Debug.Print "added to row " & FR & "; value is " & wsp.Cells(z, 2).Value & " " & catID
'                    Debug.Print "A4:A" & i
                    
                End If
            End If
        Next n
    Next z
```

in wsp I have pivot data and concatenated string to match destination table concat

[image: ![enter image description here]

Destination table looks like (you can see 0246 vs 246) - wsSUM

[image]

In the example above in pivot table is 246, in destination is 0246, but the code insert 246 (yellow cell) as the concat for both was affected by the leading zero in destination table, proper working would be to find 246 in number stored as text 0246, I need to keep formatting in destination folder, adding column to convert text to number is no the solution I would prefer as it might affect other connections

probably easiest way would be to modify concat formula to check whether destination partner ID starts with 0, 00, 000, 0000... but I would prefer some better solution, is there any way to do it? I tried ClInt, but it seems to not work on a range

```
sInt = CInt(wsSUM.Range("D4:D" & i))
```

original thread from which this issue arise [VBA Add row in table if new combination appears - partially solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71513237/vba-add-row-in-table-if-new-combination-appears-partially-solved)

Comment: It is a bit unclear and hard to understand your question because the screenshots you have don't show what you are speaking about, I can.- see any *"numbers stored as text with leading zero"* so it is hard to understand the actual problem here. Can you [edit] and give a good example of what number you are searching and how the data looks like where you are searching this number in? Maybe it's more clear then.

Comment: I added more detail in wording and also in screenshot

Comment: Do we have some more information about the PartnerID? Is it always 4 digits long (including the zeros) or can it be longer? If it is always 4 you can get the leading zeros by `ZeroID = Format$(catID, "0000")` and then search for the `ZeroID` instead of the `catID`.

Comment: It should be, but  no one will guarantee it, default value (non partner) is 6 characters long, so there is possibility that it will be larger

Comment: OK, I hate data inconsistencies, data should always be in a consistent format or you will always run into such issues. • Another question: When you run `Find()` on that data how often will it be able to find your `catID`? If it is in your data 0 or 1 time only, I might come up with a solution for that. If it is in your data more than 1 time it might get more complex.

Comment: And can you please [edit] your code and add the variable declarations and how your variables get filled with data? That would help to provide an answer. For now it is unclear what exact data is in `catID` for example.

Comment: I added full code regarding this issue; every catID should be unique for current month/quarter (highest row number = i)

CatID consist of IKOS position (SAP account number) + X99 + PartnerID + x (CatID is defined by someone else)

IKOS position is specific for every period (below 1 year...) and category (Z, O...)

Comment: Now I'm confused. So `CatID` contains the PartnerID without the zeros right? So how does the data in `wsSUM.Range("A4:A" & i)` and `wsSUM.Range("D4:D" & i)` look then? This is where your find fails right? • Or is your issue somewhere else? If you cut off the row and column names in your screenshots it's very hard to understand where your ranges refer to.

Comment: I created catid in pivot for find to add new rows, it works perfectly except the one, where in destination is leading zero, it won't find a match and add new line, therefore there is duplication of one partner 0246/246; in `wsSUM` the current period is on rows `4:i`, `CatID` on rows `4:i` is always only once; the problem here is that in pivot `CatID` doesnt contain leading zero as in destination, therefore it won't find a match and add new/duplicate line

Comment: The problem is you cut off column and row names in your screenshots, so I have no idea where `4:i` is nor where `wsSUM.Range("A4:A" & i)` and `wsSUM.Range("D4:D" & i)` in your screenshot.

Comment: ok, I added new screenshot and described what is wsp and wsSUM

Comment: OK one more question: Second screenshot column A. Is that a formula or fix value? If it is a formula which one is it?

Comment: its a formula  `=D4&"X99"&E4&"x"`

D is IKOS position, string "X99", E is PartnerID, string "x"

Comment: Can we change that formula to `=D4&"X99"&INT(E4)&"x"` without destroying anything? This would remove the leading zeros from the PartnerID, so you can use `find()` properly. Alternatively if we cannot change it, would it be possible to squeeze in another column with that formula and change `wsSUM.Range("A4:A" & i)` to that column?

Comment: sorry it took so long, have to wait for our controlling dept to reply.

so partnerID should be 4 characters long for some time as in this case it is intercompany (sorry for that, didn't have the info), so your proposal with `ZeroID = Format$(catID, "0000")` should be sufficient

as for formula edit, it is not possible as they are working with this in other processes and temporary column would be ok too, so I will go with the simplest solution `ZeroID = Format$(catID, "0000")`

Comment: Actually when you build your `catID` you need to turn your `PartnerID` (246 without the zero) into one with zero. And you do that by using `ZeroID = Format$(PartnerID, "0000")` in VBA and then build your `CatID` with that like `CatID = IOKOS & "X99" & ZeroID & x` or if using formulas you can use `=Format(PartnerID, "0000")` as a formula in a cell as well.

Comment: ok, thats correct, I used formula and it seems it is working like a charm